# Mongodb performance design

Tags: mongodb

I have the below use case.

Let's say I have user, order details in the same collection.

Id is user_id|order_id

I have the below informations in single document.

user_detail: {
   name, age, email, address
}

Assume single email, single address, single phone number field.

Then order detail which contains order id, order items, etc.

Order details contains indices also.

Note: My use case is something different I am trying to map it.

Approach 1:

Replace the order details. Replace that order wherever it is present.

Approach2:

Have a order collection, compare the changes on the order, update the changed fields where and all this order is present for that customer.

Here, order detail could be present on multiple users. Kindly assume to map my use case.

I implemented approach 2. It seems time consuming, non-scalable. I wonder which one is better or any new approaches? My concern is more about the data in the index.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The use case is not really descriptive regarding the behavior of the ordering. My suggestion would be creating another collection with the name 'cart' or 'basket' because the order is a fixed dataset regarding the products the user has ordered.

Comment: @Kevin Order is a fixed thing. Let's assume I am letting the user to modify the order till 3 days before the delivery which results in change of delivery date also. I am trying to map my use case with this.

Comment: What is a user capable of modifying of the order? Like adding new products?

Comment: @Kevin Yes. Adding removing modifying quantity

Comment: My guess would be that the quantity is defined as a field within the items of the order itself. My suggestion would be to update the quantity of the modified items within the order and not to replace the whole order. This has no impact on the performance.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks. If I replace the entire order, will it be same as updating the changed fields alone? Because mongoldb doesn't update index if it is not changed,

Comment: That depends of course on the applied indexes. For an example, if you have let say three indexes within the order details and replaced the whole order then the indexes have to be restored by MongoDB. This does not happen when you only update the quantity of that specific order. By replacing I mean, creating a whole new document with a fresh object id obtained from MongoDB.

Comment: @Kevin, thanks. Not the whole document. Only the entire order details field which itself a doc in a doc.

Comment: Then again I would only update the necessary fields, in this case quantity.